# Is TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition no longer available in Azure.Data.Tables?

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm updating a large code base from the now-deprecated `WindowsAzure.Storage` package to `Azure.Data.Tables`, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to convert my queries. I have dozens, maybe hundreds of queries built using `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` and related methods, for example:

```
var filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                 TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "PK"),
                 TableOperators.And,
                 TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "RK")
             );
```

The best I have been able to figure out, I should now accomplish this by using lambdas, a la:

```
var query = table.QueryAsync<MyEntity>(i => 
                i.PartitionKey == "PK" && 
                i.RowKey == "RK");
```

My problem is that some of my queries are complicated, and if I have to convert them all by hand like this, it will be time-consuming and error-prone. In addition, there are a few places in my code where a query filter is modified successively based on various conditions.

So I would like to continue to use the existing `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` interface if possible. So, to recap:

1. Is TableQuery deprecated in the current TableStorage APIs?
2. Is my second example above the correct, new way to perform queries?

Edit: I've started going down the path of just writing my own utility classes that present the same methods as I was using previously. However, it would be nice to use Microsoft's well-tested code if possible. I've been able to find related code in the official Azure GitHub repository, but I can't seem to find this exact code. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Closest I could find is [`TableClient.CreateQueryFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.createqueryfilter?view=azure-dotnet-preview#azure-data-tables-tableclient-createqueryfilter(system-formattablestring)).

Comment: pls add link to 'related code in azure repo'